# Using different parameters for different queries with pre get posts in functions.php

Tags: pre-get-posts, mobile, parameter

Im using pre_get_posts for my taxonomy.php for my products and paginations to work properly. And I have my `pre_get_posts` in my `functions.php`. This is how that current code looks in my functions. ( Provided by @PieterGoosen )

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) {
    if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_tax() ) {
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'name' );
        $q->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
});
```

as you can see `$q->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );` is how I set my posts per page.

and in my `taxonomy.php` I'm running my loop like so:

```
<div class="hidden-sm">

    <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    //loop content

    <?php the_field('image'); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!--hidden-sm-end-->

     //paginations   

        <?php 
        global $wp_query;

        $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

        if ($total_pages > 1){

          $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

          echo paginate_links(array(
              'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
              'format' => '/page/%#%',
              'current' => $current_page,
              'total' => $total_pages,
              'before_page_number' => '<div class="pagination-navigation">',
              'after_page_number' => '</div>'

            ));
        }
        ?>
```

loop content for mobile:

```
<div class="visible-sm">

     <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        //loop content that now shows do to media queries but now want it to be posts_per_page 6

    <?php the_field('image'); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div><--sm visible end-->
     //paginations   

        <?php 
        global $wp_query;

        $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

        if ($total_pages > 1){

          $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

          echo paginate_links(array(
              'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
              'format' => '/page/%#%',
              'current' => $current_page,
              'total' => $total_pages,
              'before_page_number' => '<div class="pagination-navigation">',
              'after_page_number' => '</div>'

            ));
        }
        ?>
```

So I have 2 different loop contents one for mobile and one for desktop version and they both  only show in a certain screen size do to media queries.

So my question is when my loop content for mobile displays how can I give that a different posts_per_page parameter if the `pre_get_posts` is set for everything in taxonomy in the `functions.php`.

Meaning that when I see everything for desktop because the screen size is lets just say over 700 px the **posts per page is 10** but when I see the loop content for mobile I want the **posts per page set to 6.**

Any idea how I can set a `$q->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );` only for another loop in `taxonomy.php` ?

**UPDATE**

Heres the same question but in a different form that may be a little bit more understandable with my goal. Ok so in my taxonomy.php I have a regular loops running

```
<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Now in my functions.php I set it's parameters for pre_get_posts with

```
$q->set( '' );
```

So as you can see my pre_get_posts code above I set all the parameters for the taxonomy page. Now lets say I wanted to run another query on taxonomy page but with different parameters how can I go about doing that. For example lets say on the side of my page im loading a query of popular items or most viewed items or whatever requires different parameter, how would I go about giving different parameters to that specific query on the taxonomy page if all the parameters have already been set with pre_get_posts in the functions? I want to give unique parameters to specific queries on my taxonomy page and not generalize everything.

Would I just run another loop but with WP_Query and set $args ?

Comment: In my honest opinion, I would really drop this and go with either 6 or 10 posts for all devices

Comment: there's no 100% reliable way to do this. the best you will ever get is it will work for *some* people.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I ask because it's not just posts_per_page but it can be many other parameter like *order_by* and other parameters. I don't want to be limited to only using one parameter for everything in one page that loads different queries. So I can probably just use 10 for all but what if I wanted to specify another parameter for another query on the same page which is very likely to happen. Thats why I want to know how to give a unique parameter on the same page but to a different query

Comment: Updated my question at the bottom.

Comment: It is unfortunately as @Milo said, it will **only** work for some. PHP was never intented to run client/browser side queries. Relying on client side stuff to make something work in php is like swimming with sharks and hoping they won't bite you.

Comment: hmm I see so even if im not "relying on client side stuff" I can't give a different parameter to a different query on the same page?

Comment: You can, if your conditions are based on php. For instance, you can set posts per page to 6 if you are viewing a tax page for term a, and set posts per page if you are viewing term b.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Ok I see now thanks really appreciate the time for helping me understand this Pieter.

Comment: From what you are asking and what you are trying to do coming from your previous question aswell, Wordpress is not the platform for you. I would recommend that you look at other platform that relies on jquery and CSS and not PHP. PHP platforms are never going to give you the type of flexibility you want. To add to this, it is as I said, one should never ever rely on client side for the pure reason, each client are different and users might turn off certain browser features that will make your intend fail